# In what scenarios can we use Wald confidence intervals

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, wald-test

In my stats course we derived Wald confidence intervals using properties such as asymptotic normality of the maximum likelihood estimator. This asymptotic normality relies on a statistical model being sufficiently 'regular'. We also defined 'regular' using a bunch of easily forgettable conditions.

I am trying to do simulation in R according to some of these models, my plan is to pick a model and compute the MLE and the corresponding Wald confidence intervals, is there a way to easily know if a model is sufficiently 'regular' i.e., how can I know whether my model will produce an estimator which satisfies asymptotic normality/ asymptotic efficiency. Are most known models regular? e.g. Poisson, exponential, binomial, gamma etc. I do not want to check the conditions as they look very technical.

Comment: Welcome to CV, delta_99. I am laughing much at this sentence, thank you! →"We also defined 'regular' using a bunch of easily forgettable conditions."

Comment: It's not just the conditions needed for the asymptotic result to hold that would be of concern (some things that do come up now and then include issues that occur at a boundary of the parameter space - particularly an issue with tests - and another is when the distribution of the statistic, or of the pivot in a CI, doesn't have finite variance). You also need to worry about "how large is large enough for the properties of the asymptotic interval - like coverage say - to be close enough to the desired properties for my purposes". Simulation can be a useful way to investigate this.